# In a similar triangle, if the property is SAS the the other two property automatically becomes true?

Tags: geometry

As we know that for any two triangles to be similar, they need to have any one of the property.

1. AAA
2. SAS
3. SSS

My question is

1. If the triangle holds the property AAA then does it mean that  SAS and SSS will also be true automatically?
2. If the triangle holds the property SAS then does it mean that  AAA and SSS will also be true automatically?
3. If the triangle holds the property SSS then does it mean that  AAA and SAS will also be true automatically?

Comment: Similar triangles do not *need* to have SSS or SAS. Congruent triangles necessarily have all three, though. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

1 No, it's easy to think up a triangle pair which share all angles but are different sizes, so they will not be congruent, and then won't satisfy the other two.

2 Yes: think about what the law of cosines says about the third side, and you'll see the triangles are congruent, even.

3 Yes: the two triangles are congruent, hence similar.